# Encourage Lavender Lady Passion flower vines to branch?

Tags: vines, branches

We recently planted a *Passiflora Lavender Lady* vine in the ground and it's growing quickly ***up*** a trellis against a fence; but is there a way to encourage it to create more branches to fill ***out*** to become more full looking?

Comment: is it planted in the ground or in a pot?

Comment: It’s in the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will branch out more over time, but these plants tend to only put up a few stems from ground level, go straight up, produce lateral growths and then those tend to spread outwards or dangle downwards. If you want flowers this year, don't cut it now, but you can cut it right down to about 6 inches in mid to late winter if it doesn't die back to ground level to try to encourage more shoots from the base. Don't prune any later than that because  this one flowers on growth it makes the  same year. Further info here [https://www.gardenia.net/plant/passiflora-lavender-lady-passion-flower#:~:text=Propagate%20by%20seed%2C%20semi-hardwood,the%20longer%20shoots%20as%20necessary](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/passiflora-lavender-lady-passion-flower#:%7E:text=Propagate%20by%20seed%2C%20semi-hardwood,the%20longer%20shoots%20as%20necessary).

Comment: That page specifically mentions _pinching_ to encourage branching. Thoughts?

Comment: You could pinch out, but possibly at  the cost of some flowers this year - I'm assuming your area counts as a 'warm weather area' which would mean you might not see the peak bloom in late summer/early fall,  but if getting  it to branch out is more important to you for this year,then yes, pinch out terminal buds.